# in Backbone: how can I make a div render upon app launch, then hide for the rest of the session?

Tags: backbone.js, local-storage, backbone-views

I'm working on an app that uses PhoneGap / Backbone.js / Thorax and Lumbar.js.

I want to show a div when the app is launched, then hide the div for the rest of the user session. Currently the user can navigate away from the launch screen, click an x to close the div and stay on the screen , or click the middle of the div that links to a new screen.

After one of these actions occurs, I want the div to be hidden for the rest of the session.

Here are relent pieces of code (in coffeescript)

Handlebars template:

```
<ul class="content-filter clearfix">
  <li><a href="" data-tab-friends>Friends</a></li>
  <li><a href="" data-tab-everyone>Everyone</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="panel post-box content-filter" id="friendBox" data-tab-friendbox>
  <div class="panel-exit" data-tab-banner-exit>
    x
  </div>
  <div id="find-people" data-tab-banner>
    <p>Find People You Know</p>
  </div>
</div>

{{#collection item-template="posts/item" item-view="posts/item" id="posts-scrollable"}}       {{/collection}}
{{view infiniteLoadView}}
```

In the view I am able to make the div close upon clicking the x and navigate to a new screen when the div is clicked:

```
"click [data-tab-banner]": (event) ->
  userId = Application.UserSession.userId()
  if userId
    Backbone.history.navigate "users/" + userId + "/follow_suggestions", { trigger: true }

"click [data-tab-banner-exit]": (event) ->
  userId = Application.UserSession.userId()
  if userId
    @$el.find('div[id="friendBox"]').remove()
```

But when I navigate back to the initial screen, the div is there again.

How do I make this appear only upon app launch, then hide for the rest of the session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest passing `{replace: true}` to `Backbone.history.navigate` so it becomes

```
Backbone.history.navigate "users/" + userId + "/follow_suggestions", { trigger: true, replace: true }
```

Quoted from [docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Router-navigate)

> To update the URL without creating an entry in the browser's history,
>   set the replace option to true.

So user can't navigate back to this state